# sequence generator and UserType

Tags: hibernate, usertype

I have a sequaance generator

```
<id name="idPersistent" type="objectID" column="aa_id">
         <generator class="sequence">
            <param name="sequence">lab_seq</param>
         </generator>
      </id>
```

objectID is my own UserType.
I got error

```
 javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: this id generator generates long, integer, short or string
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try these links, I hope these will help you

- [ID Generator bug in JPA implementation](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=970925)
- [Hibernate – Many-To-Many Example – Join Table + Extra Column (Annotation)](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-example-join-table-extra-column-annotation/)